# Why this keyword is not needed to call injected service alias

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

To call the member variable and member method in the constructor, we need to use this keyword. But why we don't need this keyword to call injected service alias.

How the below code is working, mainly commented line of code

```
constructor(private appService: AppService) {
  this.number = appService.getNumber(); // This line is working without using 'this' keyword...
  console.log(this.number);
  this.testMethod();
}
```

Can you please explain... why we don't need `this` there.

This is just example [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bs12eq)

Comment: You're working within the constructor.

Comment: Hmm, we don't generally use `this` when we try to access a parameter inside a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are inside the constructor.

If you want to call it from some other method, you will need to use `this` keyword

Example:

```
testMethod() {
  this.number = this.appService.getNumber(); // This line is working without using 'this' keyword...
  console.log(this.number);
}
```

Check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3ybv6?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

the short answer is: because it is also a variable of the constructor function.

Answer (score 2):

Because, you can omit `this` keyword in the constructor of the class.

`this` keyword is basically required to use as reference of the variable in class's other method/functions (but not required/mandatory) in the constructor.

For example -

```
constructor(private fb : FormBuilder) {
    console.log(fb);   //valid
    console.log(this.fb);    //valid
    this.tempMethod();
  }

  tempMethod() {
    // console.log(fb);   //Invalid
    console.log(this.fb);   //valid
  }
```

## [Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/constructor-instance?file=src/app/app.component.ts)